# Veteran rifles in Medal of Honor

Tags: medal-of-honor

I've just unlocked veteran rifles in Medal of Honor. To my surprise, there is no difference in stats at all. Do they provide any real advantage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, they have different looks (skins) to distinguish them from the basic models. But there is no stats advantage.

Sources:

[MoH forums](http://www.gamespot.com/ps3/action/medalofhonor/show_msgs.php?pid=980770&topic_id=m-1-57637796)

[EA Forums](http://forums.electronicarts.co.uk/medal-honor-pc/1367372-veteran-assault-rifles.html)